# Using PHP to populate a Javascript Pie Chart

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a nice JavaScript Pie chart that populates with set variable:

```
 var chartData = [{
            company: "Company #1",
            value: 260
        }, {
            company: "Company #2",
            value: 201
        }, {
            company: "Company #3",
            value: 65
        }, {
            company: "Company #4",
            value: 39
        }, {
            company: "Company #5",
            value: 19
        }, {
            company: "Company #6",
            value: 190
        }, {
            company: "Company #7",
            value: 54
            }, {
            company: "Company #8",
            value: 74
            }, {
            company: "Company #9",
            value: 98
            }, {
            company: "Company #10",
            value: 138
        }];
```

What I am trying to achieve is for the names of the company to be pulled from my MySQL database table [companies] and the values to be pulled from the same table with row [sales].

I have way more than 10 companies I do business with, but only want to chart the top 10.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Select the top 10 companies from your database.

Put them into an array.

Then `echo json_encode($myArray);`

Comment: @user1324759 Use the `limit` keyword in your query to limit the results to 10 at most.

Comment: The top companies may differ from month to month. I was hoping to find a way to populate this automatically, say from the most dollar amount showing in the database?

Comment: @Neal, Thank you sir, I will do some more looking and see if I can do what you suggest.